# Comparing two randomly generated numbers

Tags: php

I've written the following code purely to try to learn something about PHP's rand() function:

```
<?php

for ($i=0 ; ;$i++ )
{
$a = rand (1, 1000);
$b = rand (1, 1000);

if ($a == $b)
    { 
    echo "A and B variables matched at the number $a which was try number $i on the counter";
    break;
    }
else
    {
    echo "Variable a is $a and Variable b is $b on try number $i<br />";
    }
}
?>
```

The supposedly random numbers always match on one of five numbers- 458, 1722, 886, 202 or 1282.

Is the problem with my code or the rand() function?

Comment: it's the rand() function. try using mt_rand();

Comment: Wait, what? `rand(1,N)` returning values `> N`, and `< 1`? Me thinks that's not the code, or time for a reinstall (although using `mt_rand()` should be default indeed).

Comment: Over 1000 trials of your code I got 734 different results... seems like a pretty random distribution to me.

Comment: mine matched at A and B variables matched at the number 732 which was try number 246 on the counter so i think run it in incognito somtimes cached values messed with values